# If statement with not equal to condition not working as expected

Tags: python, if-statement

I have below code in python and I do not know why but it does not work as expected.

The value from variable isactive is qual to "True" and it is coming from a json dictionary. However, when I write down below if statement, the program is printing "Hola" out. Please see below code:

```
response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, params=querystring)
variable = response.text
variable = json.loads(variable)

isactive = lista1[listanumber]['IsActive']

print isactive (ourput for this is giving me "True")

        if isactive != "True":
            print "hola"
```

However, above if-statement is printing "Hola" and I do not understand why since the isactive variable is equal to "True".

Do you know what may be the problem?

Thanks

Comment: What is the string length of isactive? Is there, perhaps, some whitespace included?

Comment: what `print repr(isactive)` prints?

Comment: Uhm, it is strange..when I try to get the lenght of isactive, I got below error:                File "hoy.py", line 291, in <module>
    print len(isactive)
TypeError: object of type 'bool' has no len()

Comment: @MaximTitarenko it prints "True"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
isactive == True and isactive != 'True'
```

Test against:

```
if isactive != True:
    print 'hola'
```

Comment: Bienvenido, Jose, porfa marca mi respuesta como solución.

Answer (score 1):

A true in json is converted to python True. boolean, not string. 
In your comparison, you can then simply type `if not isActive:`